# Sql Server Optimizer: the same condition inside and outside the view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a view with some conditions and then I need to use the view but apply the same conditions on the view that I already applied inside the view. This is required by a special tool I am using.

My question is: does SQL Server optimizer recognize that the same condition is applied twice and eliminate the second condition or not always?

Example:

```
create view ViewXYZ 
as
    select x, y, z
    from tableXYZ
    where x > 0 and y = 'blabla' and z = 1000
```

When the view is created, I would like to use it like this:

```
select x, y, z 
from ViewXYZ 
where x > 0 and y = 'blabla' and z = 1000
```

Comment: This is a very strange requierment... You can check the execution plan of the query with the conditions against the query without them and see for yourself.

Comment: I tried it already, with simple conditions it works, with complicated ones sql server optimizer chooses different execution plans. I am just wondering if it optimizes something or does not check at all that the same condition is applied twice

Comment: I can't test right now but I don't think the optimizer works this way at all. I don't think it compares the conditions, it's more about choosing the best indexes to use for the query and stuff like that. It's very smart but it's not a human, after all.

Comment: Maybe not SQL Server Optimizer itself, maybe it is the preprocessor. I was just wondering if it realizes at all or not. Or if the performance is degrading after adding the same condition twice.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the conditions are [deterministic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions). For non-deterministic predicates it would be a bug to eliminate them.

But this is completely irrelevant. SQL performance comes from access path (ie. indexes), not from evaluation of expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer to the question is Yes, it simply takes the view's query and then apply the conditions on them (which are given on view) that means you are giving same conditions two times, so performance wise no change

Comment: But by testing some complicated conditions I noticed that it chooses different execution plans. This means that it not always understand that the same condition is applied twice.

Comment: @DriveAngry Because there are no absolute answers with respect to performance. Every query depends on the logic of the query, the specific content of the database,the load of the server, etc. And since you posted a trivial example but commented about "complicated conditions", then it seems you have over-simplified your particular situation. The lesson here - it's complicated and you have to test to know. And trivial tests do not give you "good" answers.

Answer (score 1):

The query is optimized as a whole structure, with the view definition effectively expanded into the outer query as a kind of macro.

The optimizer is capable of recognizing contradictions - e.g. a `WHERE` clause stating `X > 10 AND X < 5` gets optimized into not performing any table access, and I would hope that the optimizer is also capable of recognizing the stronger of two predicates (e.g. `X > 10 AND X > 20` should ignore the first predicate), but I can't point to any specific documentation on this.

Bear in mind also that, so far as possible, the optimizer pushes predicates as deep down the query as possible. So usually they'll be happening practically for free during the seek/scan of an index which is going to be incurring (relatively) high I/O costs *anyway*.